# Stop OnDrawFrame of Android GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am writing the application in which i am using GLSurfaceView to draw shapes on display.The issue is i want to pause the drawing or stop the drawing and resume it again.GLSurfaceView setRenderer is called only oncein lifetime of application.OnDrawFrame is overriden function of GLSurfaceView class os i cannot disable it.So i should i go about stopping/pausing the drawing and resume again.I am trying to draw as follows:

```
mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(mContext);
mRelativeLayout.addView(mGLSurfaceView,mRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams());
mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new LessonFiveRenderer(mContext));
```

and i am trying to pause/stop as follows:

```
mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
mGLSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface().release();
mGLSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
mGLSurfaceView.destroyDrawingCache();
//mRelativeLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
mGLSurfaceView.invalidate();
mGLSurfaceView.clearAnimation();
mGLSurfaceView.postInvalidate();

mRelativeLayout.removeView(mGLSurfaceView);
mRelativeLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
//mRelativeLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
mRelativeLayout.invalidate();
```

But the issue is the drawing keeps happening in background.How should i go about stop drawing.

Answer (score 1):

GLSurfaceView can draw continuously or on demand.  You change the mode with the [setRenderMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setRenderMode%28int%29) method.

If you pass `RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY`, your draw method will be called as quickly as the system can do so.  (This "queue stuffing" approach quickly settles to match the device refresh rate; see [this article](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops).)  If you pass `RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY`, it will only render if you call `requestRender()`.

You can see an example of this in [Android Breakout](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/).  When the game is won or lost, the GLSurfaceView is switched to render-when-dirty mode.